# WildFly 8.2.1 and nGinX

Tags: nginx, wildfly, reverse-proxy

I have 2 servers(CentOS7) in LAN WildflyAPP and nGinX.
nGinX is having 2 eth cards. One connected with LAN(192.X.X.X network) and second up to the wild world (external static IP).

I'm trying to use nGinX as Proxy to Wildfly 8.2.1(as a service) using subdomains:
app.mydomain.com to be used as proxy to Wildfly application (8080 port)
wildfly.mydomain.com for management to wildfly (9000 port)
In both cases im receiving 502 error

I used default configuration for nGinx:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.X.X.X:8080/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
    }
 }
```

I also tried versions with:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Nothing i found anywhere in net helped (standalone file checked and looks ok, APP accessible from LAN at 8080 without any problems).
Please help me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: log from nGinX [crit] 10121#0: *1 connect() to 192.X.X.X:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 194.149.88.254, server: app.mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.X.X.X:8080/", host: "app.mydomain.com"

Comment: Your problem may be SELinux/CentOS permissions related.

Comment: SeLinux is currently disabled. App server is available from nGinX server (ex using wget)